# SQLite data displayed in Toast

Tags: android, sqlite, toast

I want to display the String value of one of my data in my database inside a toast.
Here's what I've tried so far.

this is my main activity:

```
Button btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            DBUser dbUser = new DBUser(EditUserActivity.this);  
            dbUser.newNumber();
            //get the new value of the number from the DB
            Cursor c = dbUser.newNumber();
            String numberRetrieved = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")).toString();
            Toast.makeText(EditUserActivity.this,"Current Modem No. is:" + numberRetrieved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            c.close();
            dbUser.close();
     }
   });
```

and this is my method in my Database class:

```
 public Cursor newNumber() {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id=1";
    System.out.println(query);
     Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
     cur.moveToFirst();
     return cur;

   }
```

Just so you know that my database exist and it definitely has some values in it.
But whenever I run this code my application always force closes!
Hope anyone can help me in it. thanks!

Comment: Attach your stack trace.

Comment: sorry. but what is stack trace?

Comment: The stuff outputted in red in the LogCat view when your app Force Closes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String COL_2 = "DRIVERNO";
```

Please be sure your columns like this then put `COL_2` value `DRIVERNO` in `c.getColumnIndex("DRIVERNO")`
Like this

```
String numberRetrieved = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DRIVERNO")).toString();
```

I hope your app will not crash again I will solve my problem from this solution.Thanks